# If there is a sentence says "Not A or B", does it mean $\lnot(A \lor B)$ or $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$

Tags: logic

Let's say there are two fruits, apple and banana. If we consider $A : \text{Taking one fruit}$ and $B : \text{Taking both of them}$, and there is this sentence :

> Not taking one or both

Does it mean $\lnot(A \lor B)$ which according to De Morgan's law equivalent to $\lnot A \land \lnot B$, or does it mean $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From a natural-language perspective, “not taking one or both” sounds
   to me like both “not taking either one or both”, i.e., $$\lnot(A
   \lor B)\tag1$$ and “taking neither one nor both”, i.e., $$\lnot A
   \land \lnot B\tag2.$$ Fortunately, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are
   tautologically equivalent.
2. On the other hand, a literal-minded robot who isn't used to idiomatic
   expression might translate “not taking one or both” as $$\lnot A \lor
   B.$$
3. I don't think “not taking one or both” corresponds to $$\lnot A
   \lor \lnot B$$ by any means.

Answer (score 2):

It simply would be written as

$$\lnot (A\lor B)\equiv \lnot A   \land \lnot B$$

Not taking one or both is equivalent to not taking any.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it means that you don't take any of them: you don't just take one, and you also don’t take both .... i.e. you don't take any, period.

Hence it would be $\neg (A \lor B)$ or, what is equivalent: $\neg A \land \neg B$